# ajax with laravel return undefined when i echo the id but when i echo the name it works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

so i have testgroups and projects testgroup has the id of project so i can get the testgroups that has this projects and show them in my page it only echo the names but the id dont show it shows as undefined heres my ajax script

```
$("#projects").change(function(){

    var id = Number($(this).children(":selected").val());
    $("#testgroup").html('');

    $.get("/management/get-test-group/"+id, function(data, status){
        if(status == "success")
        {

            var loopdata = JSON.parse(data);

            $.each(loopdata, function(i, item) {

                $('#testgroup').append("<option  value='" + loopdata[i].testgroupid + "'>" + loopdata[i].TestGroupName + "</option><br>");

            });
            if (loopdata=='')
            {
                $('#testgroup').append("<option>" + 'No Test Groups' + "</option>");

            }

        }
    });
});
```

and heres the controller

```
public function GetTestGroup($id)
{
    $testcase = testgroup::where('project_id',$id)->get();

    if($testcase)
    {
        return json_encode($testcase);
    }
}
```

and my view i want to echo the name and the id but it only gets the name and the id shows as undefined

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label> Projects </label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="project" id="projects">
                                    @foreach($projects AS $project)
                                        <option value="{{$project->id}}">
                                            {{$project->ProjectName}}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label > Test Group </label>
                                <select name="testgroup" class="form-control" id="testgroup" >

                                </select>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you check what's field name of id of your testgroup table ? Is it "testgroupid" or simple "id" ?

Comment: its testgroupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open your model file and remove:

```
$hidden = [ 'testgroupid'];
```

After that check if it works.

Comment: dude i dont know how to thank you i been having this error for like 3 days thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

check your `testgroup` model and check if `id` is not in `$hidden` array like `protected $hidden = ['id'];` or any array that  prevent `id` to be shown;

Comment: protected $table = 'TestGroups';
    protected $fillable = ['testgroupid','TestGroupName' , 'Project_id'];
    protected $hidden = [ 'testgroupid'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'testgroupid';  this is in my model everything is good

Comment: i think problem is this `$hidden = [ 'testgroupid'];` delete or comment this piece of code.